# Exchange 2010, sending to self from Blackberry denied

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, blackberry

When I try to send an email from my blackberry to the same address, exchange denies the message with 5.5.4 5.1.0 Sender Denied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a BES server?

Comment: EDIT: beaten by joeqwerty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure authentication for sending out e-mails. I am not a blackberry user but definitely this is an authentication issue which will be the same as with any other email clients. In your email accounts settings check the outgoing mail options.